# how do i install and use a jQuery plugin in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I bought a theme on ThemeForest that uses a bunch of jQuery plugins (easytabs, datepicker, etc).  I am trying to get them to work in my Rails application.  None of them do.  Here is what I think I need to do to get them to work:

1) copy the jQuery plugin to the vendor/assets/javascripts folder 
2) require it in the application.js file 
3) call it in the [view].js.coffee file - in my case contacts.js.coffee
4) put the required HTML into the [view].html.erb file (no javascript, or the like, just inserting the appropriate ID's, etc into the section that the jQuery plugin is going to manipulate

I am clearly missing something because none of them work.  The only jQuery plugin that I have working is the DataTables one, but I followed a RailsCast for it, and installed it using its gem.  The RailsCast mentions, "fortunately, there's a gem for this or we'd have to go through and fix the broken image links..."

I'm new to Rails / web development, and I've been banging my head on this wall for a couple days now, so I don't want to blindly start updating links in a jQuery file.

How should I go about troubleshooting this?

Here the the code I've (mostly) cut and pasted:

from Application.js:

```
 WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require plugins/ui/jquery.easytabs.min
//= require_tree .
```

from properties.js.coffee:

```
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
jQuery ->
  $('#properties').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bProcessing: true
    bServerSide: true
    sAjaxSource: $('#properties').data('source')
  $('#tab-container').easytabs
    animationSpeed: 300,
    collapsible: false,
    tabActiveClass: "clicked"
```

from index.html.erb of properties:

```
<!-- Tabs -->
        <div class="fluid">
            <div class="widget grid6">       
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#tabb1">Tab active</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabb2">Tab inactive</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="tab_container">
                    <div id="tabb1" class="tab_content">
                        Tab is active and has left tabs             
                    </div>
                    <div id="tabb2" class="tab_content"> This tab is active now</div>
                </div>  
                <div class="clear"></div>        
            </div>

            <div class="widget grid6 rightTabs">       
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#tabb3">Tab active</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabb4">Tab inactive</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab_container">
                    <div id="tabb3" class="tab_content">
                        Tab is active and has right tabs               
                    </div>
                    <div id="tabb4" class="tab_content"> This tab is active now</div>
                </div>  
                <div class="clear"></div>        
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my github account, if you really want to see what I've done, in all its glory
https://github.com/jonlehman/REAPP

Comment: Hey John, what is the plugin you're installing? That seems to be all that is missing in your instructions is how the plugin interacts with your app. If I knew that, I could help you implement it.

Comment: thanks for them help.  I really appreciate it.  Lets try EasyTabs, since that is one of the ones I am trying to get working. I will add the relevant code to my original question

Comment: hmm all you need is the `require_tree` statement. i think you're loading it twice.

Comment: lol...I thought "tree" was perhaps another js file.  So, with "require_tree", why would you need to require anything else in the application.js file?  (railscast had me put require dataTables/jquery.datatables, for example)

Comment: require_tree only requires the files within the folder specified (`.` here), so it won't require the files located in `vendor/assets/javascript`, nor would it require the files within `app/assets/javascript/lala` for instance. You do need to include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your coffeescript you write

```
$('#tab-container').easytabs
```

Yet in your html there is no element with id `tab-container`, but you do use a class called `tab_container` (note the underscore), so your coffeescript should be

```
$('.tab_container').easytabs
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: changed to .tab_container...still not working.  Also, still getting that 'no method 'easytabs'' error